# Python different output for one-line if else return statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, return, tuples

While making a game of Connect Four, I encounter a strange problem in a function called `make_move`, when two equivalent return statements behaving differently.

The only direct dependency function is `put_piece(board, column, player)`, which puts a player's piece in the bottommost empty spot in the given column of the board. `put_piece` returns a tuple of two elements: the index of the row the piece ends up in (or -1 if the column is full) and the updated board. The `put_piece` function is implemented correctly.

The `make_move` function is where the disagreement occurs. It successfully returns `row` (the index of the row the piece is placed in) and `board` (the updated board) if I implement using the usual if else return notation, as shown here:

```
def make_move(board, max_rows, max_cols, col, player):
    """
    Put player's piece in column COL of the board, if it is a valid move.
    Return a tuple of two values:

        1. If the move is valid, make_move returns the index of the row the
        piece is placed in. Otherwise, it returns -1.
        2. The updated board
    """
    if 0 <= col < len(board[0]):
        return put_piece(board, max_rows, col, player)
    return -1, board
```

This is how `make_move` should return:

```
>>> rows, columns = 2, 2
>>> board = create_board(rows, columns)
>>> row, board = make_move(board, rows, columns, 0, 'X')
>>> row
1
>>> board
[['-', '-'], ['X', '-']]
```

However, if I change `make_move` to

```
def make_move(board, max_rows, max_cols, col, player):
    """
    Put player's piece in column COL of the board, if it is a valid move.
    Return a tuple of two values:

        1. If the move is valid, make_move returns the index of the row the
        piece is placed in. Otherwise, it returns -1.
        2. The updated board
    """
    return put_piece(board, max_rows, col, player) if 0 <= col < len(board[0]) else -1, board
```

Both return values get assigned as a tuple to `row`, and `board` simply carries on the previous value.

```
>>> rows, columns = 2, 2
>>> board = create_board(rows, columns)
>>> row, board = make_move(board, rows, columns, 0, 'X')
>>> row
(1, [['-', '-'], ['X', '-']])
>>> board
[['-', '-'], ['-', '-']]
```

The two ways of writing the function are literally the same except notation. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to precedence. The comma has fairly low precedence, so

```
put_piece(board, max_rows, col, player) if 0 <= col < len(board[0]) else -1, board
```

is equivalent to

```
((put_piece(board, max_rows, col, player) if 0 <= col < len(board[0]) else -1), board)
```

But you really want

```
put_piece(board, max_rows, col, player) if 0 <= col < len(board[0]) else (-1, board)
```